# Setting property inside method

Tags: c#

Is something like the following possible or do you have to return the list and assign it afterwards? I get `object reference not set to instance of an object`.

```
public class MyCollection
{
    public List<SomeObject> Collection { get; set; }

    public List<SomeObject> CreateCollection()
    {
        // Is there a way to set the Collection property from here???
        this.Collection.Add(new SomeObject()
        {
            // properties
        });

    }
}

...

MyCollection collection = new MyCollection();                    
collection.CreateCollection();
```

Comment: First, this will not compile. Your function `CreateCollection()` must return a `List<SomeObject>`, which it does not, and you are not using in your calling code.

Comment: you need to instantiate the list this.Collection = new List<SomeObject>(); and add return before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use an object initializer:

```
public List<SomeObject> CreateCollection()
{
    // You may want to initialize this.Collection somehere, ie: here
    this.Collection = new List<SomeObject>();

    this.Collection.Add(new SomeObject
    {
        // This allows you to initialize the properties
        Collection = this.Collection
    });
    return this.Collection;
}
```

Note that this will still potentially have an issue - you are never initializing `this.Collection` in any code you're displaying.  You will need to initialize it to a proper collection in your constructor or via some other mechanism.

It is also an odd choice to have a "Create" method that initializes the local variable *and* returns a `List<T>`.  Typically, you'd do one or the other.  A more common approach would be to place this code within the constructor:

```
public class MyCollection
{
    public IList<SomeObject> Collection { get; private set; } // The setter would typically be private, and can be IList<T>!

    public MyCollection()
    {
        this.Collection = new List<SomeObject>();
        this.Collection.Add(new SomeObject
        {
            Collection = this.Collection
        });
    } 
}
```

You could then use it via:

```
MyCollection collection = new MyCollection();                    
var object = collection.Collection.First(); // Get the first element
```

That being said, in general, there is no real reason to make a custom class for a collection like this *in most cases*.  Just using a `List<SomeObject>` directly is typically sufficient.

Comment: you need to return this.Collection after add the items.

Comment: @TotPeRo Already fixed - with a better design alternative suggested now, as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's completely possible - you just have to instantiate it first, before you can use it:

```
public List<SomeObject> CreateCollection()
{
    this.Collection = new List<SomeObject>(); // this creates a new list - the default if you just define a list but don't create it is for it to remain null
    this.Collection.Add(new SomeObject()
    {
        // whatever
    });
}
```

Of course, as pointed out in a comment, if you want that function to return a list, it would have to actually *return* the list. Presumably you mean `public void CreateCollection()`, though, since that was your question, whether you actually had to return a list (answer: no).

Comment: I would not check for null before adding elements, I guess that "CreateCollection" means Create, not append elements to an existing one ?

Comment: You need to add return before this.Collection.Add ...... because the method return List<SomeObject>

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize `this.Collection` before adding elements into it.

```
public List<SomeObject> CreateCollection()
{
    this.Collection = new List<SomeObject>();
    this.Collection.Add(new SomeObject()
    {
        // properties
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list initializer in this case:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    public static List<Person> Collection { get; set; }

    public static List<Person> CreateCollection()
    {

        return new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person() { Name = "Demo", Firstname = "Demo1"},
            new Person() { Name = "Demo", Firstname = "Demo1"},
        };

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Collection = CreateCollection();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might as well include the few converted lines in the `Main` function. This is so the OP knows what to call and how.